# How to Add "See more" When UILabel Over 4 rows and Show Full message When click "See more" xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, xcode7

example in link (picture)

[Show some parts of message and add "see more"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfiZJ.jpg)

[When Click see more show full message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSVz3.jpg)

Comment: Please format your question properly. A title and 2 links are not a proper question.

Comment: sorry just moment plz

Answer (score 0):

Use textview or insert a popup when text is tapped.

Comment: Now , i use Textview. and i need show 4 rows after show full message on tapped. plz help

Comment: user can scroll to see the remaining texts. they can just swipe the textview to see the full message.

Comment: Oh! sorry textview not work for my concept. I need on question. but, Thank You so much.

Comment: you can look into popovers if you want a full view of your message when a user taps it.

Comment: check uipopover, uiactionsheet, uialertview, or https://cocoapods.org/?q=alertview cocoapods. google is your friend.